# Why am I getting 'access denied for user' error in php?

Tags: php, mysql, backup, mysql-error-1045

I am running this code:

```
include '../includes/connection.php';
$conn = dbConnect('backup');

$tableName  = 'orders';
$backupFile = '../backup/db-backup(' . $date . ').sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

I am getting this error:

> Access denied for user
>   'ideapale_amadmin'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

I know the password and username is correct, and I have tested connecting to the database without running the query and that works fine. Also, the user I am currently using has all privileges. Therefore, I think there is something wrong with my sql statement.

Why am I getting the 'access denied for user' error?

Comment: There may be some small bug in your connection code.  Can you show us the connection code with the password/user name redacted?

Comment: can you do a "normal" select-statement? if yes, it's a problem with your previleges (**NOTE:** "FILE"-permissions are set global, nor for a specific database - maybe you have overlooked that)

Comment: Yes, I can do a normal select statement on the same page. How would I set global permissions on a server? I could probably figure out how to do that in phpmyadmin on wamp, but I only know how to set Privileges for a user connected to a database. Where do I set the global privileges for a user?

Comment: see my post, for global permissions, use `*.*` in your grant-statement

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to say it, but obviously the password is *not* correct. Either that or you've got incorrect privileges.

Comment: I already set all privileges. What other privileges do I need?

Answer (score 3):

already said this in my comment, but i think this is the solution:

"FILE"-permissions are set global, nor for a specific database - i think you have overlooked that, so the user has no permissions for `... INTO OUTFILE` (and, also, not for `LOAD DATA INFILE...`)

**EDIT:** the query to grant this privileges (out of my head, not tested):

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
```

**EDIT2:** to set this in phpMyAdmin, just click on `Server: localhost` (which should be the start-page when you open phpMyAdmin) then click on `Privileges`, select your user and add the tick or `FILE` in the Data-section (so, simply *don't* scroll down and select a specific database)

**EDIT3:** if you use method 1, make sure you run the grant-statement as root - a user can't grant privileges for himself (if he could, all this permission-stuff would be senseless)

Comment: How would I set global permissions on a server? I could probably figure out how to do that in phpmyadmin on wamp, but I only know how to set Privileges for a user connected to a database. Where do I set the global privileges for a user?

Comment: I get the access denied error when I try to run the sql statement you gave me.

Comment: So if I use method 1, it should be GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd'?

Comment: no, you should _log in to mysql as root_ and then `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'theuseriwanttogiveprivileges'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'theuserspasswd'`